# How is CSS getting applied without there even being a file?

Tags: html, css, flask

I do not know what is going on with my flask app. My project was fine and working the way I wanted it to then the CSS in my `style.css` randomly stopped applying to the new elements I was adding. After a bit of digging I found out that my `index.html` file was some how applying CSS by itself and not updating, so I deleted the CSS file (and other aspects of my project, like images and my second html file) and CSS still gets applied to my index.html. How? The file no longs exists and I have checked its path. Why is this? What am I doing wrong?

> Please take a look this picture of my directory, html, and web page

[image]

> Here is my Python file:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

> As you can see with this Picture this CSS file doesn't exist

[image: Picture of error]

Also, when i remove `<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/style.css">` from the top of `index.html` all the styling (apart from the in line CSS) goes away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There my be cache there for css.

You need to remove the `line 9` of your `html` file.

And remove `line 8` if you don't even want the font style.

then ctrl + F5 to force refresh with empty cache

Comment: Thank you, ctrl + F5 worked. Could you explain how cache works? I don't really understand why there would be a CSS file saved in the cache, when its not in my project.

Comment: @Jaryal Like you open a website from a webserver, your browser will download the HTML and also related JS and CSS for your HTML to work. browser will then store them on your computer temporally until you close browser or clean cache manually. See more [here](https://libguides.colostate.edu/c.php?g=64931&p=418563)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use cache killer or manually disable the cache from inspect menu. *Deleting the cache data helps to troubleshoot, helps to increase the loading time of web pages and increases the performance of your computer. If the browser doesn't load the new version of the site, even if there have been changes on the site since the last visit, the cache can cause issues with the view.*

Answer (score 0):

This is clearly coming from Cache..
**For deleting cache from chrome**
Open the Dev tools and right-click the refresh button then select "Empty cahce and Hard Reload"

**For Firefox**
simiply press "ctrl+shift+r"

*Note* - These are for Windows machine and not for Linux or Mac..